# find a data attribute just added by jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, attributes, undefined

I am adding attributes to list-items with jQuery. I am later in the code trying to access these list-items by searching for the attributes I just added, but I get "undefined is not a function".

EDIT:

This is a bigger part of my code so you can see what exactly is going on:

```
var listItems = $('#list li');
    area = '';
    subarea = '';
    for (var i in areas) {
        if (areas.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            area =  areas[i].area;
            listItems.find(".area:containsi('" + area + "')").each(function(e)
            {   
                for (var j = areas[i].subareas.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
                {
                    subarea = areas[i].subareas[j];
                    $(this).closest("li").attr("data-area", $(this).closest("li").attr("data-area") + subarea + ' ');
                }
                console.log($(this).closest("li").attr("data-area"));
            });         
        }
    }




    $('#search-input-field').on( {
        focus:  function() 
                {   
                    $(this).data('placeholder',$(this).attr('placeholder'));
                    $(this).attr('placeholder',''); 
                },

        blur:   function()  
                {   
                    $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('placeholder'));
                },  

        keyup:  function() 
                {   
                    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
                    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('");


                    listItems.attr("data-area").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e)   
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    });
```

So basically I am searching for something contained in a class inside a list item, and adding attributes to the list items data. Later I search for list items containing specific data.

The variable areas used in the for loop is an array containing information of areas with subaeras, like so:

areas = array(ID:{area, array(subareas)})

The "containsi" is just an extended version of "contains" which works perfectly, so this is not the problem.

I noticed that the data attribute that I add doesn't show in the source code, leaving me to believe that jQuery saves these attributes in some other way. I guess this is why i get the error (since the attributes search for doesn't exist in the DOMs).

Any ideas?

/Olof

Comment: not able to understand the whole logic. please share some more code as $(this) is confusing us.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, As per OP _The "containsi" is just an extended version of "contains" which works perfectly, so this is not the problem._

Comment: `.attr()` returns a string so you can't loop through it with `.each()`. Could you show an example of the data and what should looping through it even do?

Comment: @Juhana see my edit, is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful to you

Here first I write the .each() function, inside this function I am checking the attribute is present or not.

**Example Code**

```
listItems.find(".area").each(function()
            {   
                var attr = $(this).attr("attributeNameHere");
                if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                    for (var j = areas[i].subareas.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
                    {
                        subarea = areas[i].subareas[j];
                        $(this).closest("li").attr("data-area", $(this).closest("li").attr("data-area") + subarea + ' ');
                    }
                    console.log($(this).closest("li").attr("data-area"));
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to idea from Srinu

The line:

```
listItems.find(".area:containsi('" + area + "')").each(function(e)
```

led as expected to setting the data-area of the items where >area< was found in the DOM with class .area. The list items not matching didn't get any data-area, leading to a call with 'undefined' in the line:

```
listItems.attr("data-area").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e)
```